# How to Save Serialized Nested Sortable Data to MySQL Table Via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

[image]

**Can someone help me to save data from with below format to MySQL data in CodeIgniter?**

```
data: "list[1]=null&list[7]=1&list[4]=1&list[5]=null&list[3]=5&list[2]=null&list[6]=2"
```

I have a MySQL table named as menu:

```
CREATE TABLE `menu` (
  `menu_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menu_parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menu_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `menu_url` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `menu_icon` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `menu` (`menu_id`, `menu_parent`, `menu_name`, `menu_url`, `menu_icon`, `menu_order`, `created`, `updated`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Data Master', 'javascript:void(0);', '', 1, '2020-08-23 01:49:55', '2020-08-23 10:11:00'),
(2, 0, 'Transaksi', 'javascript:void(0);', '', 4, '2020-08-23 01:49:55', '2020-08-23 10:11:00'),
(3, 1, 'Jenis Layanan', 'jenis-layanan', '', 6, '2020-08-23 01:49:55', '2020-08-23 10:11:00'),
(4, 1, 'Outlet', 'admin/outlet', '', 7, '2020-08-23 01:49:55', '2020-08-23 10:11:00'),
(5, 0, 'Data Konfigurasi', 'javascript:void(0);', '', 3, '2020-08-23 01:49:55', '2020-08-23 10:11:00'),
(6, 1, 'Menu', 'menu', '', 5, '2020-08-23 01:49:55', '2020-08-23 10:11:00'),
(7, 1, 'Jenis Jabatan', 'admin/jenis-jabatan', '', 2, '2020-08-23 01:49:55', '2020-08-23 10:11:00');
```

I use jQuery plugin **nestedSortable** to dynamically re-arrange the menu hierarchy and position as below:

```
$('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
    disableNesting: 'no-nest',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    maxLevels: 3,
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div'
});
```

This is the code to try saving to database:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#ubahPosisi', function(){
    var serialized = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('serialize');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url('Menu/UpdatePosisiMenu');?>',
        data: {data:serialized},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

This my CI model for menu:

```
public function GetClientMenu($orderby = 'menu_order') {
    $query = $this->db->order_by($orderby, 'ASC')->get('menu');
    $arrData = $query->result();
    $arrTreeById = [];
    $arrChildIds = [];

    foreach($arrData AS $objItem) {
    $arrTreeById[$objItem->menu_id] = $objItem;
    $objItem->arrChilds = [];
    }

    foreach($arrTreeById AS $objItem) {
    if (isset($arrTreeById[$objItem->menu_parent])) {
        $arrTreeById[$objItem->menu_parent]->arrChilds[] = $objItem;
        $arrChildIds[] = $objItem->menu_id;
    }
    }

    array_walk($arrChildIds, function($val) use (&$arrTreeById) {
     unset($arrTreeById[$val]);
    });
    return $arrTreeById;
}

public function UpdatePosisiMenu($data = [], $id) {
    return $this->db->update('menu', $data, ['menu_id' => $id]);
}
```

And this is how I pass it to variable:

```
$this->data['menus'] = $this->m_menu->GetClientMenu('menu_order');
```

And, this is the view:

```
<ol class="sortable ui-sortable mjs-nestedSortable-branch mjs-nestedSortable-expanded">
    <?php if (count($menus) > 0): foreach ($menus as $menu):?>
    <li id="list_<?php echo $menu->menu_id;?>">
        <div class="menu-handle clearfix">
        <div class="menu-title pull-left">(<?php echo $menu->menu_id;?>) <?php echo $menu->menu_name;?></div>
        <div class="menu-option pull-right">
            <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php if (count($menu->arrChilds) > 0):?>
            <ol class="submenu">
            <?php foreach ($menu->arrChilds as $submenu):?>
                <li id="list_<?php echo $submenu->menu_id;?>">
                    <div class="menu-handle clearfix">
                <div class="menu-title pull-left">(<?php echo $submenu->menu_id;?>) <?php echo $submenu->menu_name;?></div>
                <div class="menu-option pull-right">
                    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </ol>
        <?php endif;?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; endif;?>
</ol>
```

And, lastly the CI controller to execute the saving:

```
public function UpdatePosisiMenu() {
    $data = $this->input->post(null);
        $sort = [];
        if (!empty($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $id => $ParentID) {
            $ParentID = ($ParentID === null) ? 0 : $ParentID;
            if (!array_key_exists($ParentID, $sort)) {
                $sort[$ParentID] = 1;
            }
            $this->m_menu->UpdatePosisiMenu(['menu_parent' => $ParentID, 'menu_order' => $sort[$ParentID]], $id);
            $sort[$ParentID]++;
        }           
    }   
}
```

And, I got this foreach error during saving:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: controllers/Menu.php
......
```

Comment: and where is the problem? can explain what is not working in your code?

Comment: This is it: `data: "list[1]=null&list[7]=1&list[4]=1&list[5]=null&list[3]=5&list[2]=null&list[6]=2"`. I'm trying to save it to MySQL and had no idea.

Comment: what shows: print_r($data) in your controller? it looks like $data - which actually represents your $_POST array - is not empty, but not an array neither

Comment: It returns the error as above. If only printing the $data, it will return this `data: "list[1]=null&list[7]=1&list[4]=1&list[5]=null&list[3]=5&list[2]=null&list[6]=2`. Agree that the passed data from jQuery nestedSortable serialize is not an array and I have no idea how to transform it to the proper array format during jQuery transaction.

Comment: I've tried this tuts also but still no luck. [link](https://webmobtuts.com/javascript/using-jquery-nestedsortable-plugin-to-sort-hierarchical-lists/)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue with this update:

1. table schema still is the same
2. modification for the jQuery script:

   ```
   var menuarray;
   $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
       disableNesting: 'no-nest',
       forcePlaceholderSize: true,
       handle: 'div',
       helper: 'clone',
       items: 'li',
       maxLevels: 5,
       opacity: .6,
       placeholder: 'placeholder',
       revert: 250,
       tabSize: 25,
       tolerance: 'pointer',
       toleranceElement: '> div',
       relocate: function(){
           menuarray = $(this).nestedSortable('serialize');
           console.log(menuarray);
       }
   });

   $(document).on('click', 'a#ubahPosisi', function(){
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '<?php echo base_url('Menu/UpdatePosisiMenu');?>',
           data: {data:menuarray},
           dataType: 'JSON',
           cache: false,
           success: function(response) {
               if (response.success == true ) {
                   window.location.reload();
               }
           }
       });
   });
   ```
3. create helpers that will be used to build the menu contents

   ```
   function prepareList(array $items, $pid = 0) {
       $output = array();
       foreach ($items as $item) {
           if ((int) $item['menu_parent'] == $pid) {
               if ($children = prepareList($items, $item['menu_id'])) {
                   $item['children'] = $children;
               }
               $output[] = $item;
           }
       }
       return $output;
   }

   function nav($menu_items, $child = false) {
       $output = '';
       if (count($menu_items) > 0) {
           $output .= ($child === false) ? '<ol class="sortable">' : '<ol>' ;
           foreach ($menu_items as $item) {
               $output .= '<li id="list_' . $item['menu_id'] . '">';
               $output .= '<div class="menu-handle clearfix">';
               $output .= '<div class="menu-title pull-left">(' . $item['menu_id'] . ') ' . $item['menu_name'] . '</div>';
               $output .= '<div class="menu-option pull-right"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span></div>';
               $output .= '</div>';
               if (isset($item['children']) && count($item['children'])) {
                   $output .= nav($item['children'], true);
               }
               $output .= '</li>';
           }
           $output .= '</ol>';
       }
       return $output;
   }
   ```
4. modify the model code

   ```
   public function buildMenu() {
       $this->db->select('menu_id, menu_parent, menu_url, menu_name, menu_order');
       $this->db->order_by('menu_parent, menu_order');
       $menuItems = $this->db->get('menu')->result_array();
       return prepareList($menuItems);
   }
   ```
5. grab the menu data in controller and view the menu contents in respective view file

   ```
   <?php echo nav($menus);?>
   ```
6. and finally the magic code to save the menu group or order as you wish

   ```
   public function UpdatePosisiMenu() {
       $data = isset($_REQUEST['data'])? $_REQUEST['data'] : '';
       $status = ['success' => false];
       parse_str($data, $arr);
       if (isset($arr['list'])) {
           array_walk($arr['list'], function(&$val, $key){
               $this->m_menu->UpdatePosisiMenu(['menu_parent' => $val, 'updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')], $key);
           });
           $status['success'] = true;
       }
       echo json_encode($status);
   }
   ```

And, this is how it looks now:

(https://www.flickr.com/photos/189950440@N02/50283999368)

Comment: `isset($_REQUEST['data'])? $_REQUEST['data'] : '';` can be shortened to `$_REQUEST['data'] ?? '';`.  `buildMenu()` can enjoy less repetitions of `$this->db` by using "method chaining".  `isset($item['children']) && count($item['children'])` can be shortened to `!empty($item['children'])`. `count($menu_items) > 0` can be shortened to `$menu_items`.  Since you are using a loose comparison, remove the `(int)` before `$item['menu_parent'] == $pid`. `response.success == true` can be shortened to `response.success`.

Comment: Oh, what a tricks!. Thanks for sharing the useful tips. Anyway, originally I thought there will be a moment someone will need to see the complete steps. But, I use your tips in my productivity actually.